# How to explode date like 09.06.2010 and get the "2010" with php?

Tags: php, explode

How to explode date into pieces and get last part from it. Lets say, we have 09.06.2010 and we wanna get "2010" from it.How to do it with php?

Comment: Why not actually parse the date and extract the year properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this method:

```
end( explode( '.', $date ) );
```

**OR**

```
date( 'Y', strtotime( $date ) );
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$sDate = "09.06.2010";
$aDate = explode(".", $sDate);
$iYear = $aDate[2];
var_dump($iYear);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are other methods, like parsing the date. But you asked:

```
$date_output = explode('.', $date_input);
$date_output = $date_output[2];
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean like 4 last digits of such string?

```
substr("09.06.2010",-4);
```

Although just like Pekka says in his comment, doing actual date processing will make your code more robust and easier to change in future.

Comment: how can i do that? please explain

Comment: Something like Galen's second solution (using `strtotime()` and `date()`) is a good start. Suddenly you can now support a whole range of different date formats like `09.06.2010`, `2010-06-09` or `June 6th, 2010`.

Answer (score 1):

if you always want the last position, you can try with strrpos(), it will find the last occurrence of a given character. So you may do:

```
$string = '11.22.3456';

$pos = strrpos($string, '.');
$year = ($pos !== false) ? substr($string, $pos + 1) : 'N/a';

var_dump($year);
```

explode() is always an option, just wanted to give another one.

Answer (score 0):

```
$timestamp = time();
list($dd, $mm, $yy) = explode('.', strftime('%d.%m.%Y', $timestamp));
echo $mm;
```

See: [strftime](http://php.net/manual/de/function.strftime.php)

See: [list](http://php.net/manual/de/function.list.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
function dateExp($date, $sign=null, $argIndex = '0'){
        $exp = null;
        if(!empty($date) && !empty($sign)){
            $exp = explode($sign, $date);
        } else {
            $exp = explode('/', $date);
        }
        if($argIndex!=='0'){
            $exp = $exp[$argIndex];
        }
        return $exp;
    }
$setDate = '2015-10-20';
$date1 = dateExp($setDate,'-');
print '<pre>';
print_r($date1);
print_r($date1[0]);
Output:
Array
(
    [0] => 2015
    [1] => 10
    [2] => 20
)
2015
```